# How to reload current page in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm current in `/id/1234` page, and click a `POST /add` button, after that I want to reload `/id/1234` in Experss.js:`res.redirect(**How to get /id/1234 dynamicly, since I will be in /id/1235, /id/1236 page do a same POST /add action?**)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 78):

I'd just like to add that in the version 4.x of Express you can use

```
res.redirect('back');
```

to automatically redirect back to the page the request came from.
This is the equivilant of

```
res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
```

that is mentioned in [Peter Lyons answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15827882/1153203)

See also: http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: this is a good way for times that you have a middleware that validate inputes and after that want to send errors to the get request route to show the errors. (i'm not englishman, so i'm sorry)

Answer (score 20):

To give you the answer you probably want, the browser will send a header called `[Referer][1]` which will have the URL of the `/id/1234` page, so do:

```
res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
```

However, your URL path design is probably poor if you need to do this. Better options might be submitting the form via AJAX without changing the URL or including the `1234` id in the form body and using that value from the POST request to generate the correct URL for the corresponding redirect.

Answer (score 16):

I use express 4.x
you can write like this

```
res.redirect(req.originalUrl)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
res.redirect("/id/1234")
```

You just give the path (or full URI) that you wish to redirect to.

And if you're id is in the post data:

```
res.redirect("/id/" + req.body.id);
```